# Blur div блока css

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что бы фон `div` блока с `class="blur"` был заблюрен.

Нужно сделать размытие только фона блока, а не его содержимое.

```css
body {
background: url(https://oboitut.com/uploads/posts/2019-01/thumbs/oboitut.com_1548668534.jpg) 100% 100%;
width: 600px;
height: 412px;
background-size: cover;
}
.blur {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="blur">
BLUR
</div>
</body>
```